# Java problem in PowerShell 'Could not determine jave version from '14'

Tags: java, windows, powershell

I can't run the command `.-gradlew setupDecomWorkspace` in PowerShell, I get this error, help and thanks :)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '14'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  PS C:\Users\Green\Desktop\forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2768-mdk>

Comment: Java 14 support was added in [Gradle 6.3](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html#support-for-java-14). What version of Gradle are you using (you can check with `.\gradlew --version`)?

Comment: @Slaw I' cant run `.\gradlew --version` command, I don't know what to do, how do I upgrade to gradlew 6.3?

Comment: Perhaps you need to downgrade Java, if the library you're using doesn't support Java 14. Or use a later version of your library.

Comment: Forge 1.12.2 isn't compatible with Java 14, which may be the issue. Try installing Java 8  to see if you have better results.

Comment: @Iain bro, already install the jdk 8, how do I configure it to be used by the powershell?

Comment: Hmm. Either or both of these will be needed: 1) Update your PATH to point to the Java 8 bin directory instead of the java it is pointing to now 2) Update JAVA_HOME to point to the Java 8 directory. PATH/JAVA_HOME are environment variables, for more information on how to change environment variables: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: When updating your PATH, be sure to leave all other entries intact. Order matters, so I recommend adding the path to java 8 towards the beginning.

Comment: @Iain oh men, thank you, I had been in forums and guides for over a week but I couldn't find the solution, thanks bro

Comment: You're welcome. :)